# Wierd compiler error in GCJ

Tags: java, gcj

I was trying to compile some java codes using gcj. I am getting following error. Is it because something in that line is not supported by my gcj? Btw, I am using gcj to see if native codes are any better than bytecodes with latest hot-spot JVMs.

> AbstractCursor.java:113: error: '{' expected. public abstract class
>   AbstractCursor implements Cursor {
>                                          ^ AbstractCursor.java:113: confused by earlier errors, bailing out

Thanks
~ Reaz

Comment: It would help if you posted the code you are trying to compile. If it is a big program, post a short sample program that reproduces the error.

Comment: Probably the next symbol _after_ that is erroneous like `(`. Note that an anonymous initializer starts with `{`.

Comment: Best way to figure out confusing compiler errors is by reducing the code to the smallest that gives the error. Usually the errors jumps at you somewhere along the trimming, if not post it on SO :)

Comment: If we could see the code it would be easier to help

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, my (wild) guess: the line number 113 seems to indicate, that this is maybe the second class definition in the source. There may be only one non-inner **public** class in a .java file.

Or this is an inner class but braces are nested wrong.